# difference between magnetic dipole moment and torque on a magnetic dipole?

Tags: momentum, torque, dipole, magnetic-moment, dipole-moment

I am a bit confused.
What is the difference between magnetic dipole moment 
and torque on a magnetic dipole ?

Answer (score 0):

I magnetic dipole can be modelled by a small coil of wire. The dipole moment of such a coil is defined to be $$\vec m=I\vec A$$ Where $I$ is the current and $\vec A$ is the area vector (that is the area multiplied by a unit vector perpendicular to the plane. The torque on a dipole is the sum of $$\vec \tau =\vec r \times \vec F$$ for each force  $\vec F$ applied at position $\vec r$. If you work this out for a magnetic dipole in an external magnetic field $\vec B$ you will find that: 
$$\vec \tau=\vec m \times \vec B$$

Comment: What does this imply? The bigger the dipole moment,the quicker the magnetic dipole will align with an external magnetic field?

Comment: Don't forget the mass of your particle.

Comment: @JaqcuesMartin yes, but as HolgerFiedler pointed out it also has to do with the mass and since we have a cross product the angle between the magnetic field and the dipole moment. But for a given mass and angle then a dipole with a greater dipole moment will align with the field faster then one with a smaller one.